# what is the best way to sync SQL Server with Interbase database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, synchronization, interbase, kinterbasdb

I need to sync SQL server database with the Interbase DB. Interbase is the live DB and main application works on this. Now customer wants to cerate an SQL server database and sync it with the live interbase database once everyday. All historical reports will be generated from the SQL Server database.

The Interbase DB does not have timestamp or any column that contains time. Hence I cound not found any way to identify new (and modified also) records. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [CopyTiger](http://www.copycat.fr/feature-list/copytiger-feature-list.html)